# Dados do formulário não são cadastrados no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Galera me ajuda. Seguinte: eu tenho aqui um formulário html o qual eu envio os dados do form para um email através do action. Só que, antes de enviar para o email eu quero que esses mesmos dados sejam inseridos no banco de dados. Par isso, eu criei um php que faz o envio dos dados para o banco e eu tenho um outro php que envia os dados para o email (no form do html eu uso o php do email e não do banco. Isso tá certo?).

```
<form action="contatoTeste.php" method="POST" role="form" name="contatoForm" id="contatoForm">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group"> 
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" name="nome" required placeholder="Nome">
                                                 <span class="erro"><p id="nome_erro"></p></span>
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group"> 
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" required placeholder="Sobrenome">
                                                 <span class="erro"><p id="sobrenome_erro"></p></span>
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="input-group"> 
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email">
                                                     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                      <span class="erro"><p id="email_erro"></p></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" required placeholder="Telefone">
                                                    <span class="erro"><p id="telefone_erro"></p></span>
                                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem aqui..." class="form-control" rows="9"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                           </form>
```

e agora o php do banco de dados:

```
if ((isset($_POST['email']))&&(!empty($_POST['email']))){

//verifica se existe conexão com bd, caso não tenta criar uma nova
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","aquivaimeuusuario","aqui a senha") //porta, usuário, senha
or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados"); //caso não consiga conectar mostra a mensagem de erro mostrada na conexão

$select_db = mysql_select_db("aqui vai o nome do meu banco"); //seleciona o banco de dados

//Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POST
$nome = $_POST["nome"]; 
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$assunto = $_POST["assunto"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];

$string_sql = "INSERT INTO contatoCadastro (Nome, Sobrenome, Email, Telefone, Assunto, Mensagem) VALUES ('{$nome}','{$sobrenome}','{$email}', '{$telefone}', '{$assunto}', '{$mensagem}')"; //String com consulta SQL da inserção

mysql_query($string_sql,$conexao); //Realiza a consulta

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){ //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
    echo "<p>Cadastro feito com sucesso</p>";
    echo '<a href="contact.html">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
} else {
    echo "Erro, não possível inserir no banco de dados";
}

mysql_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados 

} else{
    echo "Por favor, preencha os dados";
}
```

Minha pergunta é: Como eu faço para os dados irem para o banco? No meu formulário HTML eu tenho que chamar esse arquivo php que postei aqui ou o outro arquivo php que envia os dados do contato para o email? Se sim, como eu faço para poder enviar os dados para o banco de dados e em seguida enviar para o email?

Galera muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu sou iniciante em php e não sei fazer corretamente essas relações. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Use mysqli ao invés de mysql, ele foi obsoleto!

Comment: Valeu Francisco pela dica. Mas não solucionou meu problema. Continuo sem gravar os dados no banco.

Comment: Posta o erro...

Comment: Olha o erro que tá rolando agora: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/ceugo406/public_html/insereDadosContato.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/ceugo406/public_html/insereDadosContato.php on line 23
Erro, não possível inserir no banco de dados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Formulário**

O formulário, já que não apresenta erros, permanece o mesmo.

```
<form action="contatoTeste.php" method="POST" role="form" name="contatoForm" id="contatoForm">
..................
..................
```

**PHP**

Pode usar apenas um arquivo para realizar as duas operações, enviar email e registrar no banco.

***contatoTeste.php*** (nome dado no action do formulário)

```
if ((isset($_POST['email']))&&(!empty($_POST['email']))){

//verifica se existe conexão com bd, caso não tenta criar uma nova
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","aquivaimeuusuario","aqui a senha") //porta, usuário, senha
or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados"); //caso não consiga conectar mostra a mensagem de erro mostrada na conexão

$select_db = mysql_select_db("aqui vai o nome do meu banco"); //seleciona o banco de dados

//Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POST
$nome = $_POST["nome"]; 
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$assunto = $_POST["assunto"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];

$string_sql = "INSERT INTO contatoCadastro (Nome, Sobrenome, Email, Telefone, Assunto, Mensagem) VALUES ('{$nome}','{$sobrenome}','{$email}', '{$telefone}', '{$assunto}', '{$mensagem}')"; //String com consulta SQL da inserção

mysql_query($string_sql,$conexao); //Realiza a consulta

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){ //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
    echo "<p>Cadastro feito com sucesso</p>";
    echo '<a href="contact.html">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
} else {
    echo "Erro, não possível inserir no banco de dados";
}

mysql_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados 


/******* CODIGO EMAIL *******/

// Uma dica para envio de emails
// Baixe os arquivos  PHPMailerAutoload.php  -  class.smtp.php  -  class.phpmailer.php em github - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
//Crie uma pasta  PHPMailer-master no mesmo diretório da sua aplicação PHP e publique os arquivos baixados nesta pasta (PHPMailer-master).

require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.kithomepage.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Autenticação
$mail->Username = 'USUARIO@DOMINIO.COM'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'SENHA'; // Senha da caixa postal utilizada

// Define o remetente
$mail->From = $email; 
$mail->FromName = $nome. " " .$sobrenome ;

// Define o(s) destinatário(s) 
$mail->AddAddress('fulano@dominio.com', 'Fulano');
//$mail->AddAddress('destinatario2@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário');
//$mail->AddCC('destinatario3@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário'); // Copia
//$mail->AddBCC('destinatario4@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário'); // Cópia Oculta


$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

$mail->Subject  = $assunto; // Assunto da mensagem

$mail->Body = $mensagem;

$enviado = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";

echo "Informações do erro: 
" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}


/******* FIM CODIGO EMAIL *******/

} else{
    echo "Por favor, preencha os dados";
}
```

> Como já é do conhecimento geral, a função mysql_connect() ficou obsoleta no PHP 5.5.0 e as funções mysql_ * foram removidas no PHP7! Saiba mais com [[[image]]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869)

### Com MySQLi a conexão pode ser feita do seguinte modo:

```
if ((isset($_POST['email']))&&(!empty($_POST['email']))){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "USUARIO";
    $password = "SENHA";
    $dbname = "NOMEdoBANCO";

    $conexao = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conexao) {
        die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $string_sql = "INSERT INTO contatoCadastro (Nome, Sobrenome, Email, Telefone, Assunto, Mensagem) VALUES ('{$nome}','{$sobrenome}','{$email}', '{$telefone}', '{$assunto}', '{$mensagem}')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$string_sql);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) >0){ //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
      echo "<p>Cadastro feito com sucesso</p>";
      echo '<a href="contact.html">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; 
      //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
    } else {
      echo "Erro, não possível inserir no banco de dados";
    }

    mysqli_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados

    /******* CODIGO EMAIL *******/
    .............................
    .............................
```

Comment: Gente vocês são f@#$#@oda, obrigado demais. A conexão com o banco foi feita e após isso os dados foram enviados para o email. Só que eu não entendi o que pode ter acontecido que no banco de dados, só mostra, por exemplo: id 1 e id 2 e os outros atributos da coluna não mostram no banco. Fiz uma consulta no próprio banco para ver se o atributo nome por exemplo estava salvo mas não retornou nada, que não foi encontrado. É algo no código q precisa ser alterado?

Comment: Quando eu faço um cadastro no site, ele manda para o banco de dados e preenche apenas o id e os outros campos não mostram nada. É como se os outros dados não tivessem ido, não entendi. Alguem sabe o que pode ser? Estou usando o phpMyAdmin servidor.

Comment: Gente, já descobri meu erro. Antes de passar os dados para o banco eu não tava pegando as variáveis do formulário. Agora deu certinho, todos os dados foram preenchidos corretamente no banco de dados e após isso enviado para o email. Gente, muito obrigado MESMO ! Valeu demais pela força de todos que vieram aqui contribuir comigo. Thank you guys.

Comment: @GuilhermeSchults, mas na sua pergunta tem lá no `php do banco de dados:` os $_POST pegando os dados do formulário. De qq forma se está funcionando certinho é o que importa. Não deixe de ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Fiz algumas modificações no arquivo no seu código php, tente algo assim espero ter ajudado.

**contact.html**

```
<form action="contatoTeste.php" method="POST" role="form" name="contatoForm" id="contatoForm">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group"> 
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" name="nome" required placeholder="Nome">
                                                 <span class="erro"><p id="nome_erro"></p></span>
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group"> 
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" required placeholder="Sobrenome">
                                                 <span class="erro"><p id="sobrenome_erro"></p></span>
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="input-group"> 
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email">
                                                     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                      <span class="erro"><p id="email_erro"></p></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" required placeholder="Telefone">
                                                    <span class="erro"><p id="telefone_erro"></p></span>
                                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem aqui..." class="form-control" rows="9"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
                           </form>
```

**contatoTeste.php**

```
<?php 


$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'test';


if ((isset($_POST['email']))&&(!empty($_POST['email']))){

//verifica se existe conexão com bd, caso não tenta criar uma nova
$conexao = new mysqli("$servidor","$usuario","$senha","$banco"); //servidor, usuário, senha, banco
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falha na conexão: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
 //caso não consiga conectar mostra a mensagem de erro mostrada na conexão


//Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POST
$nome = $_POST["nome"]; 
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$assunto = $_POST["assunto"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];

$string_sql = "INSERT INTO contatoCadastro (Nome, Sobrenome, Email, Telefone, Assunto, Mensagem) VALUES ('{$nome}','{$sobrenome}','{$email}', '{$telefone}', '{$assunto}', '{$mensagem}')"; //String com consulta SQL da inserção

$query = $conexao->query($string_sql); //Realiza a consulta

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) >= 1){ //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
    echo "<p>Cadastro feito com sucesso</p>";
    echo '<a href="contact.html">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
} else {
    echo "Erro, não possível inserir no banco de dados";
}

mysqli_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados
}
```