# Enviar e-mail e gravar registro automaticamente no BD (chamados)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Tenho a seguinte necessidade. Estou criando um sistema de chamados para um cliente em PHP, e tudo será registrado no banco MySQL e pra cada resposta, será encaminhado um e-mail (via PHPMailer, por exemplo).

Preciso que, ao responder esse e-mail enviado, essa mensagem seja registrada no banco de dados também. Porém, não faço a minima ideia de como proceder ou o que procurar.

Eu sei que tal recurso existe, pois já respondi alguns chamados com essa funcionalidade. Mas não sei como é feito.

Alguém tem alguma luz de por onde começar?

Comment: isso pode lhe ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248803/dados-do-formul%C3%A1rio-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-cadastrados-no-banco-de-dados/248831#248831

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu não sei se fui eu que não achei, ou se realmente não tem sobre isso no link que você passou. O que ele quer acredito que ser capturar um conteúdo de um e-mail e registrar no BD. Na verdade tem um detalhe muito importante acredito eu, que seja uma caixa de e-mail para uso do sistema, assim todo e-mail respondido, deve ter uma cópia para o "e-mail do servidor" e essa caixa ele lê, filtra, e registra. Seria isso !?

Comment: Maykei, no título "Enviar e-mail e gravar registro automaticamente no BD" dá-se a entender que você quer responder o chamado e envia e-mail disso (se você responde o chamado, já está gravando no banco provavelmente). Nessa parte "Preciso que, ao responder esse e-mail enviado, essa mensagem seja registrada no banco de dados também.", subentende-se que você quer que o sistema "leia" a resposta do e-mail, e grave isso no BD. Explique melhor qual dessas seria seu caso.

Comment: @RBZ Preciso que o sistema leia a resposta do e-mail e grave no BD, é isso mesmo! Porém, não sei como proceder, já que nunca fiz nada parecido (leitura do conteúdo de um email via PHP).

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo na verdade o link que você mandou é de um envio de email via PHP. Não é isso que preciso. Preciso meio que o processo inverso. O PHP capturar os e-mails enviados para uma determinada caixa, por exemplo (chamados@meudominio.com), e através de um ID no titulo, inserir o conteúdo do email no meu banco de dados, para mantê-lo atualizado de qualquer interação, seja via e-mail ou via sistema!

Comment: @MaykelEsser conheço um sistema que faz isso (Movidesk), apesar de ser horrível a interface, me chamou a atenção essa função. Dê uma olhada nesse [LINK](https://www.gigasystems.com.br/artigo/97/ler-email-do-servidor-com-imap-e-php) . Pode ser que tenha alguma biblioteca para isso. Seria uma mão na roda.

Comment: @RBZ acho que temos um ponto de partida sim! Aí é comigo! Muitissimo obrigado! Essa função do IMAP vai ser de grande utilidade!

Comment: Pois é, o mal é ler somente o titulo da pergunta, sorry!!